# Random numbers from an array and delete in C

Tags: c, arrays, random

I am writing a very simple program, yet I can not seem to get it to work properly. I want to start with an array with numbers from 1-69 and then randomly select 5 numbers from this array without repeating. And I do not want to just shuffle the array and take the first 5 numbers. I want it to resemble more of a darwing numbers out of a hat with the probability being the way it should be.
For Example:

Array1[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

Array2[]

// I want it to randomly choose an element from Array1, remove it from Array1, and place it in Array2. Then repeat the process until I have 5 randomly pulled numbers from Array1 without repeating.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank You!

P.s. I am writing this project in C.

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: There have been several recent questions on this theme. Have a little search of the C pages about random, and more generally, the Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: The mathematically correct way to do this is to shuffle and pick the first five--you can save time by short-circuiting the shuffle after five loops so you don't have to shuffle all 69 items. The fact that you think this is somehow not "properly" simulating a draw from a hat without replacement is just a bias of your human mind. Learn the math and do it right.

Answer (score 4):

Pseudo-code:

1. Create 69-element array `A[]` with values [1 ... 69].  `Length = 69;`.
2. Randomly create an index `index = rand()%Length;`
3. Swap that indexed element `A[index]` with array element `A[Length-1]`.
4. Decrement: `Length--`
5. Repeat steps 2-4 four more times.
6. The last five elements of `A[]` are the desired set - no repeats.

Note: code is not shuffling the complete array - which would be a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply "remove" a cell in a C array; if you really want to do it that way, the best you can do is:

- select the element with rank *n* (from array A) and do whatever you want with it
- move elements *n+1*, *n+2*, etc. (from array A) one cell left (backward) with something like `memcpy`
- remember the new size of the array A (because the allocated memory will remain the same during the whole process)

Answer (score 0):

1. You absolutely need to just "try something", post your work, and ask questions about what you've tried.  Especially if this is a homework assignment, we can't "do your work for you" :(
2. There are many ways you can approach this.
3. Some example options:

   a) Fill the array with "legal" numbers, select five numbers from five random positions, then mark those positions "taken" (so they won't be selected again).

   b) Randomly fill the array with legal numbers, and choose five at a time, starting with position "0".  Increment current position by "five" each time.

   c) Etc.

Answer (score 0):

"I want it to resemble more of a darwing numbers out of a hat." That is exactly how you can implement this:

- Create a `hat` array with all lottery ticket in it.
- Pick a random ticket from the array, store it and remove the ticket from the hat.
- Repeat until you have as many tickets as you need.

Deletions from arrays require the tail of the array being shifted, but you don't need that here: The order of the items in the hat isn't important, so you can move the last element to the gap the drawn ticket has left in the array and decrement the array length.

So:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int hat[70];        // pool of numbers
    size_t n = 70;      // size of pool
    size_t i;

    // get pseudo-random-number generator underway
    srand(time(NULL));

    // fill pool with all numbers
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) hat[i] = i;

    // pick five numbers and print them
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        size_t pick = rand() % n;

        printf("%d\n", hat[pick]);
        hat[pick] = hat[--n];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In your case, the number of drawn numbers is small in comparison to the pool, so you might actually look at things the other way: Instead of restricting the items that you draw, you could look at the items you have already drawn and draw a ticket until you get one that you haven't seen yet. But the method above is genneral.